How to Adjust Time Intervals in react-native-calendars to Less Than 1 hour/30 minutes
I'm using the react-native-calendars library in my React Native project to display a timeline view with events scheduled throughout the day. By default, the time intervals on the left side of the timeline are set to 30 minutes, as shown in the image below:
Screenshot of the calendar
I'd like to modify these time intervals to display every 15 minutes instead of the default 30-minute intervals. I want more control over how these intervals are displayed to better match my scheduling needs.
Here’s a brief summary of my setup:
Library: react-native-calendars
Component: TimelineList within a CalendarProvider
Current Behavior: Time intervals are fixed to 30 minutes (e.g., 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, etc.).
Expected Behavior: Ability to set time intervals to 15 minutes or another custom duration.
What I've Tried:
I've looked through the documentation and explored various props and methods, but I couldn't find an option to adjust these time intervals.
`
     <CalendarProvider   date={dayPressed ?? DateTime.now().toISODate()}
        onDateChanged={(date) => { setDayPressed(date) }}
      >
        <ExpandableCalendar
          firstDay={1}
          onDayPress={(day) => { setDayPressed(day.dateString); }}
        />
        <TimelineList
            timelineProps={{
              start: startHour,
              end: endHour,
              unavailableHoursColor: "rgb(235, 235, 235)",
              onBackgroundLongPress: handleBackgroundLongPress,
              onEventPress(event) {
                openEventModal(event);
              },
              renderEvent: renderEvent, 
              theme: customTheme,
            }}
            events={events}
            showNowIndicator
            scrollToFirst
            initialTime={INITIAL_TIME}
          />
      </CalendarProvider>`

